# Axios does not send the form data to the controller

Tags: laravel, database, vue.js, rest, axios

I'm trying to take the name of the list from a sweetalert input and pass it with axios to the CategoryController in order to add it to the database with the add_list() function

SideVav.vue :

```
const { add_list } = useList()

const listName=ref()

function addList() {

            const inputValue = ''

            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Add List',
                input: 'text',
                inputLabel: 'Enter the list name',
                inputValue: inputValue,
                showCancelButton: true,
                background: '#fefbe9',
                confirmButtonColor: '#007E33',
                allowOutsideClick: false,
                inputValidator: (value) => {
                    if (!value) {
                        return 'You need to write something!'
                    }
                }

            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    listName.value = result.value

                    add_list(listName.value)

                }
            })
        }
```

lists.js :

```
const add_list = async (data) => {

        let formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('name', data);

        axios.post('/api/dashboard/addlist', formData).then(response => {
            console.log(response)

            if (response.data.success) {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Success!',
                    text: response.data.success,
                    icon: 'success',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
                    confirmButtonColor: '#007E33',
                    background: '#fef6dd',
                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                })

            }else{
                alert('err')
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

Here axios does not send formData in CategoryController.

CategoryController.php :

```
public function add_list(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $category = $request->all();

        Category::create($category);

        return response()->json(['success' => "The list '" . $request->name . "' successfully created"]);
    }
```

At the end, no list was added to the Categories table.

Plssss help me!

Comment: Can you use `Inspect` tool in the browser and see whether you have any logs in the `Network` tab when Axios is calling the endpoint? If so, please add it to the question. It may help you to answer this question.

Comment: The state is 200.  I don't have errors. It is very strange!

Comment: Not sure, if you are checking the correct response. so, I would suggest you to check  if you are missing CSRF token for this `POST` request.

Comment: I checked the request header and I found  X-XSRF-TOKEN.

Comment: Everything looks as if there is no problem. But it does not work!

Comment: Are you sure your endpoint is expecting a multipart/form-data content type and not json?

Comment: In the request headers, I have - Content-Type:multipart/form-data and in the response headers, I have - Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8.  Here is the problem? I have to change with application/json? If so, how?

Comment: What do you have if you log the request in your controller ?

Comment: Object { data: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }
​
config: Object { timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN", … }
​
data: ""
​
headers: Object { "access-control-allow-credentials": "true", "access-control-allow-origin": "http://127.0.0.1:8000", "cache-control": "no-cache, private", … }
​
request: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​

Comment: I get an empty object.  It looks like the formData is not being sent to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I believe since you are posting formData, and axios presumes json, you might have to pass in a header telling the server it's formdata you're posting.

```
const headers = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
};

axios.post('/api/dashboard/addlist', formData, headers).then(response => {})
```

This might help.

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work, it's obsessing me :((

Comment: What happens if you var_dump($request); in your CategoryController.php? @CosminCarbunaru